# Unexpected iOS App size increase with TestFlight

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, app-store-connect, testflight

We are making a game for iOS (under unity 3d) and the IPA file size is around 90 MB. We submitted it for review and at the same time we pushed that same build to Test Flight for Internal Testers. Surprisingly the size on Test Flight is now 400 MB (uncompressed size).

We used test flight internal testing for previous versions of the game, but never got this much size.

Anybody having any clue as how the test flight is taking up the uncompressed file and showing that for the download (400 MB to download)?

Also after we set it for release, which size will the app be for people to download, 90 MB or 400 MB?

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you, it would be helpful for others if you accept that answer. If not, feel free to comment on the answers given, or update your question.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get an idea of the App Store size is to follow the analysis here:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/il2cpp-build-size-improvements.322079/

TL;DR

Due to compression of some parts of the binary, a rule of thumb formula for the app size is:

```
app_store_size = sizeof(.ipa/(zip with exec_binary removed)) + sizeof(codesegment(exec_binary)) + 0.2 * sizeof(datasegment(exec_binary))
```

This analysis only takes a look at the binary size, so you need to add the size of any assets as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm not sure how you send your app to TestFlight, but if you are using App Loader or XCode, you could uncheck the field "include bitcode", I'm not sure if it's set by default.

This is how it looks in XCode (while exporting archive):
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Art/6_ios_review_dist_profile_2x.png

The thing is, iTunes will create different binaries for your application each optimized for different versions of devices (like different versions of iPad, iPhone etc.). That is why your application on TestFlight has such huge difference in size in comparison to your ipa file.

Comment: I use App Loader for uploading it to TestFlight. And, no, I didn't got any checkbox for "bitcode". I used to apply the same settings and methods for previous versions also and it never got that big.

Comment: Check out this documentation for more details: https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html

I'm not sure how this applies to projects on Unity, basically iTunes will set AppThinning by default as far as I understand. This does not mean the app will have 400MB in size once it is installed on a device. The whole idea behind it is to optimize it for each device (if they are on iOs9 +).

Comment: Some details about Unity and app thinning are available here: http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/28/optimizing-ios-app-size-with-resource-slicing/

Answer (score 0):

Check the contents of the IPA. It probably contains debug symbols in the DSYM folder. As il2cpp output is very big, so will be the symbol files. I suppose they are included in the Testflight upload because these are meant for QA purposes, where debug symbols are very helpful.